# Creating a Sequence of Sounds using Table

Tags: sound

I am trying to play a sequence of sounds in Mathematica using `Table`. My real example is much more complicated so that is why I got to using `Table`,

Why doesn't the follow code work?

```
frequencies = {{100, 200}, {200, 300}, {400, 600}};
Sound[
  Table[
    Sound[Play[Total[Sin[# 2 Pi t] & /@ frequencies[[i]]], {t, 0, 0.5}]], 
    {i, 1, 3, 1}]]
```

If I run the sounds as a list it works fine, but when using table it does not, I just get the following:

> ```
> Sound[{Sound[
>    Sound[SampledSoundFunction[
>      Function[{Play`Time494}, 
>       Block[{t = 
>          0. + 0.000125 Play`Time494}, (Total[(Sin[#1 2 \[Pi] t] &) /@ 
>             frequencies[[i]]] - 4.44089*10^-16) 0.568158]], 4000, 
>      8000]]], 
>   Sound[Sound[
>     SampledSoundFunction[
>      Function[{Play`Time495}, 
>       Block[{t = 
>          0. + 0.000125 Play`Time495}, (Total[(Sin[#1 2 \[Pi] t] &) /@ 
>             frequencies[[i]]] + 1.88738*10^-15) 0.525731]], 4000, 
>      8000]]], 
>   Sound[Sound[
>     SampledSoundFunction[
>      Function[{Play`Time496}, 
>       Block[{t = 
>          0. + 0.000125 Play`Time496}, (Total[(Sin[#1 2 \[Pi] t] &) /@ 
>             frequencies[[i]]] + 8.88178*10^-16) 0.525731]], 4000, 
>      8000]]]}]
> ```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4):

I get something like this

```
frequencies = {{100, 200}, {200, 300}, {400, 600}};
Sound[Table[
  Evaluate@Sound[
    Play[Total[Sin[#*2 Pi t] & /@ frequencies[[i]]], {t, 0, 
      0.5}]], {i, 1, 3, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it plays sound when clicking on the pay button. (just added `Evaluate`). See if this is what you expecting the sound to be. I am not good with music.

Comment: This gives an error. Evaluate should come before Total. The correct version is: Sound[Table[
  Sound[Play[
    Evaluate@Total[Sin[#*2 Pi t] & /@ frequencies[[i]]], {t, 0, 
     0.5}]], {i, 1, 3, 1}]]

Answer (score 1):

This code is written by Shenlan.

```
 Block[{s1 = "C", s2 = "D", s3 = "E", s4 = "F", s5 = "G", s6 = "A", 
      s7 = "B", t1 = 0.25, t2 = 0.5}, 
     Sound[SoundNote @@@ {{s3, t1}, {s3, t1}, {s4, t1}, {s5, 
         t1},(*||*){s5, t1}, {s4, t1}, {s3, t1}, {s2, t1}, {s1, t1}, {s1, 
         t1}, {s2, t1}, {s3, t1},(*||*){s3, t2}, {None, t1/2}, {s2, 
         t1/2}, {s2, t2},(*||*){s3, t1}, {s3, t1}, {s4, t1}, {s5, 
         t1},(*||*){s5, t1}, {s4, t1}, {s3, t1}, {s2, t1},(*||*){s1, 
         t1}, {s1, t1}, {s2, t1}, {s3, t1},(*||*){s2, t1}, {None, 
         t1/2}(*Rest*), {s1, t1/2}, {s1, 2 t1},(*||||*){s2, t1}, {s2, 
         t1}, {s3, t1}, {s1, t1},(*|*){s2, t1}, {s3, t1/2}, {s4, 
         t1/2}, {s3, t1}, {s1, t1},(*|*){s2, t1}, {s3, t1/2}, {s4, 
         t1/2}, {s3, t1}, {s2, t1},(*|*){s1, t1/2}, {s2, t1/2}, {s5, 
         t1}, {s3, t1/2}, {s3, t1/2}, {s3, t1}, {s4, t1}, {s5, t1}, {s5, 
         t1}, {s4, t1}, {s3, t1/2}, {s4, t1/2}, {s2, t1/2}, {s1, t1}, {s1,
          t1}, {s2, t1}, {s3, t1}, {s2, t1}, {None, t1/2}(*Rest*), {s1, 
         t1/2}, {s1, 2 t1}}]]
```